# Can a Gaussian process have a degenerate sub-collection?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution

The following is from [Rasmussen and Williams (2006)](https://gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf):

> A simple example of a Gaussian process can be obtained from our Bayesian linear regression model $f(x)=\phi(x)^Tw$ with prior $w\sim\mathcal N(0,\Sigma_p)$. We have for the mean and covariance
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \mathbb E[f(x)]&=\phi(x)^T\mathbb E[w]=0\\
> \mathbb E[f(x)f(x')]&=\phi(x)^T\mathbb E[ww^T]\phi(x')=\phi(x)^T\Sigma_p\phi(x')
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> Thus, $f(x)$ and $f(x')$ are jointly Gaussian with zero mean and covariance given by $\phi(x)^T\Sigma_p\phi(x')$. Indeed, the function values $f(x_1),f(x_2),\ldots,f(x_n)$ corresponding to any number of input points $n$ are jointly Gaussian, although if $N<n$ then this Gaussian is singular (as the joint covariance matrix will be of rank $N$).

The joint distribution of $f(x_1),f(x_2),\ldots,f(x_n)$ is degenerate if $n$ is larger than the dimension of $w$. Can we still say then that $f(x_1),f(x_2),\ldots,f(x_n)$ are jointly Gaussian? Can $f(x)$ still be called a Gaussian process?

Comment: What makes you think it is not a Gaussian process? For example, Brownian motion starting at $0$ is degenerate at $t = 0$, but still a Gaussian process.

Comment: @G.Chiusole I just want to make sure I clearly understand the definition of a Gaussian process. So, every finite sub-collection of a Gaussian process has a multi-variate Gaussian "distribution" but does not necessarily have a multi-variate Gaussian probability density function. Is that correct?

Comment: Here is an extreme case. Let $Z$ be a (real-valued) standard Gaussian random variable and $X_t=tZ$ be a random process indexed by $t\in\mathbb R$. Then, the distribution of any two random variables $X_{t_1},X_{t_2}$ is degenerate. Is $X_t$ a Gaussian process?

Comment: exactly, a Gaussian process is one where the marginals are Gaussian. Those marginals may not have a density function though. Conventions may differ, but I have never seen degeneracy being excluded. As for your example, yes, that is a Gaussian process.